# R9 -5950x ( X570-ACE )

Tags: graphics

I have the following specs for a build with Ubuntu, can you suggest which version of Ubuntu would support ?

Here is the specs given bellow ;

Here is the complete list of components for the build with detail description

### CPU-
AMD R9-5950X 16c / 32 threads

MB-
ASUS PROWS X570-ACE -

RAM-
T-FORCE 128GB 3200Mhz RGB DDR4 (32x4)-

M.2 SSD
CORSAIR 2TB MP600 M.2 NVME -

VGA-
MSI RTX3090 SUPREME X 24GB GDDR6X -

PSU
Corsair RM850W MODULAR 80 PLUS GOld -

CASE
Corsair 680X 4 FANS RGB Black -

LIQUID COOLER
Corsair H115i Platinum  RGB LIQUID COOLER

please the above mentioned is the build , confirm me if this will support Ubuntu and which version !

Thank you !

Comment: Any Ubuntu flavor will run fine with that hardware capacity. Nobody here will likely know exactly which bits of hardware will work out of the box, so you'll have to test that yourself by booting to a live USB and seeing if things work. Chances are the whole thing will work just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer !!

Answer (score 0):

Components that are (afaik) oficially supported:
PSU,
Case,
Liquid cooler,
vga,
m.2 ssd

Components that work if you can POST:
CPU,
MB,
RAM,

Conclusion:

It will work, if you can get into the BIOS (you can do xmp and cpu overclock there). I've heard that you might have some speed issues before driver installation and kernel updates.

Answer:
You can use any ubuntu (x86 = x86), but for optimal performance and support, use 20.04 LTS. If you want the newest of everything and don't mind updating every 6 months, use 20.10. If you want a windows alike look, use Kubuntu.

Comment: So are you saying this specs would be working perfect ?

Comment: I don't know why they wouldn't. I cannot test them here (its too hard to buy it), but I know that nVidia has official linux support for RTX 3090, and any x86 (ryzen, core, athlon) will work on linux